# Why am I receiving "error connected to db server: no reachable servers" after importing GZipped Archive file(.agz) to Studio 3T?

Tags: mongodb, docker, gzip, mongodump, studio3t

I have my database running on a docker container and I want to upload data stored in GZipped Archive file (.agz) to Studio 3T using Mongodump import. However, when I click execute it returns an error: "Import mongodump archive error connecting to db server: no reachable servers".

I have tried unzipping file, re-establishing local connection to docker container, dropping collection before importing, and all the other types of imports.

After trying the "Another Collection" import, importing the file appears to be successful with a green checkmark but logs 0 files uploaded. Every other import gives the

```
Import mongodump archive error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: how you start db container? is there any logs from container?

Comment: I start db container in a Makefile which contains this code:
```
-@docker run --rm -d --net $(PROJECT)_net -v $(PROJECT)_db:/data/db -v $(PROJECT)_configdb:/data/configdb --name $(PROJECT)-mongo-db -p 27017:27017 mongo:3

and there are no logs